# Display MessageBox in ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I am new to code and starting with ASP. How do I create a simple message box so I can alert the users on the web page?

Comment: Is this old classic ASP or ASP.NET?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
    <%
       Dim message    
       message = "This is my message"
       Response.Write("<script language=VBScript>MsgBox """ + message + """</script>") 
    %>
```

Comment: @AnthonyWJones, Very true, I agree, TheTXI has a better solution using javascript.

Comment: Client side VBScript is long dead.

Comment: @ShadowWizard this answer was 6 years ago

Comment: So what? So change it to use JavaScript, at least. Even old IE browsers support it, so I would have downvoted 6 years ago as well.

Comment: It's fine you downvoted it, doesn't bother me. I'm going to leave it as it is, because it's an alternate solution, even though it is no longer used. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: I think its useful because many classic ASP sites were using VBScript as the scripting language.

Answer (score 33):

```
<% response.write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('Hello!');</script>") %>
```

Comment: This worked great. Thanks! I am going to stay away from Javascript for a while and stay with the ASP VBScript for now. I appreciate your feed back!

Comment: If that is how you wish to do it, but I would suggest rethinking your stance on JavaScript just because you'll probably end up using it much much more down the line. Also, there are many many more JavaScript resources and tutorials out there.

Comment: This one is much better approach for logging or tracking as VBScript is not available for all browsers.

Answer (score 7):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
    alert("Hello!");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Copy Paste this in an HTML file and run in any browser , this should show an alert using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it from code behind, try this:

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "AlertBox", "alert('Message');", true);
```

Comment: This is ASP.NET while question here is for classic ASP. Answer not relevant.