# Trying to create a messagebox or alert which displays the value of an asp-classic variable

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic, vbscript

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956977/asp-messagebox) and tried the first suggestion, and while it will display what I need it to, I suddenly get lots and lots of javascript errors. It's generating about 30 `expected end of statement` errors.  The message box works great though, which is why I'm trying to figure out if there's another solution to pop-up the value of an ASP variable.  I'm trying to get it to display inside of an ASP function.

Comment: Can you post your javascript?

Comment: I don't really have any that's related to the message box.  It's just all of the javascript I've used in my page.  It's over 1700 lines.  It doesn't error if I remove that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

I ended up using this:

```
    %><script language=javascript>
    var temp = '<%=message%>';
    alert(temp);
    </script><%
```

I don't know why I didn't think to do that before!

Answer (score 0):

I had to work with some legacy code recently and had this same problem.  This will work as well if the variable was previously defined:

```
Response.Write "<script language='JavaScript'>alert('The value is " & variable_name& "');</script>"
```